# Making a movie from images

Tags: matlab

I have a folder with a name (Photos) and it is containing four subfolders with names (Order1, Order2, Order3, and Order4).

Each folder containing 100 images. I am trying to make a movie for each subfolder. I will get four movies. I used the below code and its read images from each folder automatically and create movies and save it in the same folder.

So, I got four movies. The problem that there is jump during the movie, so picture number 1 is repeated many times during the video at different times. How can I correct the code? Or is there some other code that can accomplish this job?

```
startpath = pwd;

for k = 1:4
    folder = fullfile(startpath, 'Photos', sprintf('Order%d', k));
    cd(folder)
    Files = dir('*.jpg');
    NumFiles= size(Files,1);
    Megamind_Images = uint8(zeros([600 1000 3 NumFiles*5]));
    VideoObj = VideoWriter('Create_Video.mp4','MPEG-4');
    VideoObj.FrameRate = 5;
    VideoObj.Quality   = 80;
    count=1;
    for i = 1 : NumFiles
        I = imread(Files(i).name);
        ResizeImg = imresize(I,[600 1000]);
        for j = 1 : 5
            Megamind_Images(:,:,:,count)=ResizeImg;
            count = count + 1;
        end
    end
    open(VideoObj);
    writeVideo(VideoObj, Megamind_Images);
    close(VideoObj);
end
```

Comment: Do the picture file names follow a pattern, so that you could generate the filenames sequentially?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is start from 1 to 100

Comment: So then you can generate the filenames in a `for ii=1:100` loop with something like `filename = sprintf('picture%d.jpg', ii);`, yeah?

Comment: or even better, `filename = fullfile(startpath, 'Photos', sprintf('Order%d', k), sprintf('picture%d.jpg', ii));`, sparing you a `cd`. Obviously, you'd want to include the folder in `VideoObj = VideoWriter(...,'MPEG-4');` as well.

Comment: Thanks. I still face the same problem. I used movie maker to build movie and it is work fine. However, I want to use MatLab code to do that

Comment: in your loop that handles the files, can you `fprintf('Current file: %s\n', filename)` to check the files are processed in the right order? Also are the actual files in the right order?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is according to the numbers.

Comment: i don't really understand the use of this loop, could you please clarify it to me?         
    for j = 1 : 5
            Megamind_Images(:,:,:,count)=ResizeImg;
            count = count + 1;
        end